# Why is this failing to apply transform:none to my elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following being invoked inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

```
var serviceIcons = $('#services-row img');
for (var k = 0, n = serviceIcons.length; k < n; ++k) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        $(serviceIcons[k]).css('transform', 'none'); 
    }, k * 50);
}
```

and I've verified that `$('#services-row img')` is returning the correct set of objects, but I'm not seeing the attribute `style="transform:none;"` on the `img` applied to the `img`s. The corresponding CSS is:

```
#services-row img { 
    transform: translateX(-10000px) translateY(-10000px); 
    transition: transform 1s; 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget vendor prefixes!

Comment: Your for loop has invalid syntax I believe in the condition.

Comment: The `for` loop syntax is fine.  This is a closure issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time the timeout function is called, the `k` variable has already finished looping, and it will always be equal to `serviceIcons.length` within the function.

To access the loop value, use this syntax instead:

```
setTimeout(
  function(k) {
    return function() {
      ...
    }
  }(k), k * 50
);
```

So your final code would be:

```
var serviceIcons = $('#services-row img');
for(var k = 0, n = serviceIcons.length; k < n; ++k) {
  setTimeout(
    function(k) {
      return function() {
        $(serviceIcons[k]).css('transform', 'none');
      }
    }(k), k * 50
  );
}
```

See http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside for a good description of this solution.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9bvvjpe/2)